# Split a given string into equal parts where number of sub strings will be of equal size and dynamic in nature?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, web, data-structures

I have read many answers on stackoverflow but , unable to find the solution.

Let say we have a string `'Hello World'`. The idea is to split `Hello World` into equal parts.

Example:

`'he','ll', 'ow', 'or','ld'`

The string can be of N characters and each time, the string has to be split of equal substrings.
Incase of `hello World` we had `hello worlds` the split strings would be,

`'he','ll', 'ow', 'or','ld', 's'`

Note that there is no N supplied on which the string can be divided into. The N here is dynamic based on the string supplied. So N can be 2,3,4...N, depending on the string size.

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: @NinaScholz On what basis will you split the string? How will you determine N?

Comment: To clarify, you have the string length N (which is known) and then some length O which is the size of each segment that the N length string should be split into. Each segment has to be the same length. O, expect the last one in case the string can't be split evenly into O sized strings. Can the function decide O on its own own? What would drive an O = 2 vs O = 3?

Comment: @Milton Yes. The function should determine O dynamically so that all the substrings are of equal length and if there are extra characters left they can left grouped into a separate string.

Comment: Based on what requirements? What's stopping it from always using O = 2, and if it's an odd length string it will just have a single character segment at the end? Should it try to find the largest possible O that is still of equal size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the length of the substrings and iterate until the end of the adjusted string.

```js
function split(string, size) {
    var splitted = [],
        i = 0;
        
    string = string.match(/\S+/g).join('');
    while (i < string.length) splitted.push(string.slice(i, i += size));
    return splitted;
}

console.log(...split('Hello World', 2));
console.log(...split('Hello Worlds', 2));
```